# Is exporting of the 3D drawing from GeoGebra 5 possible?

Tags: technical-drawing

My apologies if this is an off-topic question here.

I'm trying to get any export (Asymptote, TikZ or PSTricks) of the 3D drawing from [GeoGebra 5.0](https://www.geogebra.org/). Once I've got some 2D drawing, everything seems all right (see the first screenshot), but after I change anything to the 3D world (Point C in the example), the exporting is not functional/programmed? (see the second screenshot). It looks it's a problem for all three export options (Asymptote, TikZ and PSTricks). Do you have the same experience as I do?

Working export of the 2D drawing (PSTricks):

[image: 2D example]

A try of exporting the 3D drawing (PSTricks):

[image: 3D example]

Comment: That feature probably isn't implemented yet. It definitely wasn't in November last year: http://forum.geogebra.org/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=37433&p=135119&hilit=tikz#p135119 Anyways, I think this is off-topic here, it's really just a question about Geogebra.